# Setup clean URLs like CodeIgniter

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I like the way CodeIgniter cleans URLs for sites, however, I have a site that is too involved to start over using the CI framework (at least for now), and I don't need the depth CI provides, I only have one level deep.

Is there an easy way to do this easily using straight PHP?

```
index.php?id=2454
index.php/2454/
```

**NOTE:** I need a straight PHP solution because the server is Windows and .htaccess is not setup to work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "cleans URLs"?  Perhaps provide some examples of how you'd like certain URLs to change?

Comment: If you're running on Apache, you can look into how to use the mod_rewrite module.

Answer (score 1):

If you use mod_rewrite in apache you can allow your application to dispatch requests as you want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Say your server is located @ http://coolguy.com and a users accesses http://coolguy.com/mycleanurl/

With the above rewrite rule in your .htaccess or apache configuration you can intercept which url is being accessed via $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] and send it off to the specific code point you want.

The "RewriteCond" directives i have in there are used to ignore this rewrite rule if there exists a file directly at the location the user has specified, this is handy for static assets like CSS and images where you dont want to have to dispatch these requests yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` - it returns anything trailing the script filename but preceding the query.

For example, in the URL:

`http://www.domain.com/index.php/var1/var2`

`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` would contain `/var1/var2`

You could then write a function in your `__construct()` or `init()`, etc, to parse the path (e.g. `explode("/", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])`) and use the resulting array as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache? If so, look into files called `.htaccess`. They rewrite the URL when they're stored in your directory. So if you put an `.htaccess` file in your web root with

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

then when a person goes to the URL `yourdomain.com/page1`, it will actually retrieve the resource `yourdomain.com/www/page1` on your server, but their browser won't see the www.

So, for very simple URL rewriting you can use this to hide the `?var=val&var2=val2` crap in the URL

Information on the rules is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your using PHP on windows and want to do URL Rewriting you have two choices:

- Url Rewrite (which allows you to use rewrite rules in the web.config) http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite - Open the site in IIS Manager and select "Url Rewriting", then add your rules.
- Buy Helicon-APE or similar (which allows you to use a native .htaccess file)  http://www.helicontech.com/ape/ - we use this on our shared windows hosting servers with great success

Comment: I appreciate a non htaccess answer. Are those both installation required packages? It is a shared host, so I can't install.

Comment: Most (99%) of shared hosts will have UrlRewrite already installed, so you just have to add your rules to your web.config

Comment: I already looked into it. For the time being, I am grandfathered on an old plan that doesn't offer it. I am already in works to finally upgrade to a modern plan though.

Comment: <rewrite>
 <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={R:1}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
</rewrite> inside  <system.webServer>

Comment: What version of IIS is it? If 7/7.5 You could write a HttpModule/Handler that could do the request rewriting manually without too much effort. If IIS6, you would need to get your host to configure "All Requests" to be handled by the HttpHandler.

Comment: Ultimately though, getting put onto a modern plan is going to be the easiest and cheapest option.

Comment: IIS 6.0. Seems an upgrade is in my best interests.