# CodeIgniter URL Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

My current url is http://localhost/ci/ which is also set under config.php

but how do I open other pages in views without specifing index.php

http:/localhost/ci/Pages/view/login but not like this http:/localhost/ci/index.php/Pages/view/login

Comment: you dont open files from view folder directly. Its not work like that

Comment: CodeIgniter has some documentation on setting up "RewriteRules" for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup clean URLs like CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161171/setup-clean-urls-like-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/

you can do alot with `.htaccess` file
try putting this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 ^(Pages|view|login|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use application/config/routes.php file.

Add URL Routing definition is very simple with it.

See this link for more information: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html